# BibLaTeX: Remapping groups field as keywords field doesn't work

Tags: biblatex

I want to use the groups from my literature management tool as keywords for `BibLaTeX` to create specific bibliographies for certain chapters. I managed to remap the groups field as a keywords field if an entry contains both fields, however, this seems not to work. How do I have to adjust the `\DeclareSourcemap` command to make this work? Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
  ]{biblatex}

  \DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=groups, fieldtarget=keywords]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
  @article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = {bar},
    groups  = {foo}
}

  @article{redwade93,
    author  = "George D. Redwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    groups  = {foo}
}

  @article{bluewade93,
    author  = "George D. Bluewade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = {bar}
}
\end{filecontents}

  \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

This document contains citations of \cite{greenwade93}, \cite{redwade93} and \cite{bluewade93}---but \cite{greenwade93} doesn't appear in the first bibliography.

\printbibliography[keyword=foo,title={Bibliography One}]

\printbibliography[keyword=bar,title={Bibliography Two}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `biblatex` is very reluctant to change or overwrite existing fields. You will have to encourage it with `overwrite=true`.

Up to and including version 2.7 of Biber the `fieldtarget` approach seems to have trouble with existing fields even if `overwrite=true` us enabled, however. You could use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
       \step[fieldsource=groups]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

This will simply overwrite `keywords` with the content of `groups`.

This problem is fixed in version 2.8 (DEV version, not yet released), so we can then use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
       \step[fieldsource=groups, fieldtarget=keywords]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to collect both fields into `keywords` use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
       \step[fieldsource=keywords, final]
       \step[fieldsource=groups]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=groups]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

With this `groups` is copied to `keywords` if the latter does not exist; the contents of `groups` is appended to `keywords` if there already are some keywords present (note that we need to insert a comma, so we can't do both steps in one go).

Comment: Because I didn't understand why `fieldtarget` would not work with `overwrite=true`, I asked on the `biblatex` bugtracker: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/535

Comment: The fieldtarget overwrite bug is fixed in the current DEV version of biber (2.8).